# Crop an Image Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am googling from last few hour and get solution for crop an Image, But I am confused and  wants to know what is the difference between these two?

Problem : I wants to crop a rectangle image from inside an Image, I already detected the boundary.[image]

First :

```
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320, 460);

// Create bitmap image from original image data,
// using rectangle to specify desired crop area

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageView.image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *imgs = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Second :

```
CGRect rect = [backView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[backView.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: have a look on these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578821/iphonehow-to-crop-image-in-ios5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950719/how-to-crop-the-image-in-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method is more general, in that your `backView` needs not to be an `UIImageView`, like in the first case.

In other words, `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` requires you to have a CGImage to start with:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageView.image CGImage], rect);
```

on the other hand with `renderInContext` you can render any view into an image:

```
[backView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```